# Train a ANN with 2D output

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I am trying to train an ANN with the 2D target in the format below:
targets=[(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,0,0)]
the size of my features is (5996, 5) and targets are (5996, 3), I tried to use the code below:

```
num_outputs = 3
num_elements = 3

ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8,activation="relu"))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=64,activation="relu"))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=8,activation="relu"))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,activation="sigmoid"))

ann.add(tf.keras.layers.RepeatVector(num_outputs))
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.TimeDistributed(tf.keras.layers.Dense(num_elements)))

ann.compile(optimizer='adam',loss = 'binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

ann_history=ann.fit(X_trn, y_trn, batch_size = 25, epochs = 100)
```

but I receive this error:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: [25,3] vs. [25,3,3]
 [[node gradient_tape/binary_crossentropy/mul/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at <ipython-input-102-9ad8105af048>:1) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_103981]
```

Function call stack:
train_function

Can you please help me with this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try a 1D output of 9 elements and then transform the data into two dimensions after the ANN completes.

```
# replace this line    
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1,activation="sigmoid"))

# with this line
ann.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=9,activation="sigmoid"))
```

Being a universal approximator the ANN should give you correct results. The only problem with this solution is you will have to create extra steps when training and testing because the data that immediately comes out of the ANN will not match the target data, but a simple transformation will correct any errors.